# Рассылка уникальных писем на почту (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, email, рассылка

Подскажите в какую сторону думать.

Выполняю рассылку сразу на несколько адресов. Формирую view, который и отправляется на адреса. Каждое письмо должно содержать уникальное имя пользователя из выборки всех пользователей. Соответственно, view должен быть у каждого пользователя свой.

Вопрос в этом и заключается - как сделать уникальный view для каждого письма в рассылке?

Так я написать не могу, так как все пользователи получат одинаковое письмо со списком всех имен пользователей:

```
$foreach ($users as $user)
{{ $user->name }}
@endforeach
```

А как сделать чтобы каждый получил свое имя в письме?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

````
$emails = array("myemail1@email.com", "myemail2@email.com");
$input = Input::all();

Mail::send('emails.admin-company', array('body' => Input::get('email_body')), 
function($message) use ($emails, $input) {
    $message
    ->from('admin@admin.org', 'Administrator')
    ->subject('Admin Subject');

        foreach ($emails as $email) {
            $message->to($email);
        }
});```
````